# Correspondence between paths in path space and path homotopies

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

This problem is on Introduction to Topology by Gamelin and Greene. (chapter 3 part 2 exercise 6)

> Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and let $a,b\in X$. let $\mathscr{P}$ be the set of all paths in $X$ with the metric $$\rho(\alpha,\beta)=sup \{d(\alpha(s),\beta(s)):0\leq s\leq 1\}$$ Show that two paths $\alpha,\beta \in \mathscr{P}$ are homotopic with endpoints fixed if and only if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ lie in the same path component of $\mathscr{P}$.

One side is easy, but for the other side knowing that $\alpha,\beta$ are homotopic then there is a map $F:[0,1]^2\to X$ such that $F(s,0)=\alpha(s),F(s,1)=\beta(s),F(0,t)=a,F(1,t)=b$. Now let $F(s,t)=\gamma_t(s)$. Then the function $t\to \gamma_t$ seems like it can be a path between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the path space, but we need to prove that this map is continuous, then given that $\gamma_0=\alpha , \gamma_1=\beta$ it would indeed be a path between the two in the path space.
I've failed to show the continuity of it and I'am stuck here.

By the way, this question has been posted before; but the confusions are different. Also the other post is from 5 years ago so I won't have any luck asking my question there! Please don't close it!

Comment: the compactness is used implicitly to make $\rho$ a well-defined metric.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks. What does the metric $\rho$ do though?

Comment: it defines a topology so that continuity and path-connectedness makes sense at all.

Comment: Wait sorry I asked the wrong question I'm going to edit my post!!!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sorry I edited the post can you look at it again?

Answer (score 1):

If $p: [0,1] \to \mathcal{P}$ is a path from $\alpha$ to $\beta$, then

$H(x,t) = p(t)(x)$ seems to me a natural candidate for a homotopy between those paths.